# Why does Application.LocalUserAppDataPath throw System.NotSupportedException?

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2010, windows-server-2012

In our environment we development boxes in several flavors of Windows Desktop (7 & 8).  Our build server is Windows Server 2012 R2.  When we build one of our applications on a developer machine it builds and runs just fine on any system (Windows 7, 8, and 2012).  When we build on the build server (2012), it builds fine, but does not run on any system (Windows 7, 8, or 2012).

In debugging (on the 2012 system), I find that Application.LocalUserAppDataPath is throwing a System.NotSupportedException.

Any clues on why that might be happening?

I have seen elsewhere noted that if the running user does not have a profile, LocalUserAppDataPath will throw an exception.  However, the user we are building (and running my tests) with does have a profile.

Comment: what is the full message?

Comment: are they roaming profiles?

Comment: The full message is:  {"The given path's format is not supported."}  No, the user is a local user for the machine.

Comment: The actual stack shows the exception starting in "CanonicalizePath"

Comment: are the user profiles on a file share? from what i can tell from reading the reference source, that if that isn't on a mapped network drive or physical drive, it will throw that exception.

Comment: see: http://referencesource.microsoft.com/#mscorlib/system/security/util/stringexpressionset.cs#9962e430aeafa4ab

Comment: It's on a local drive.  So it should be fine.  In looking at the source it specifically is looking for the ":" when it throws the exception.  So, the question would become: Why does it have a 'correctly' formatted path when built on Windows 7/8 and a bad path when built on Windows 2012?  To answer that, I'd want to see the path strings it is using...

Comment: If you want to see the strings, why not use Visual Studio remote debugger?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer is that the path built in this situation was a bad path.

The build machine had automated information added to the assembly information files.  I was unaware of the use of the AssemblyCompany element in building paths.  The contents of this element was incorrect as a path (contained a ":" character).

Props to David A. White for pointing to the reference code which also contains instructions on debugging the .NET code.  This allowed me to see the problem.